# Laws pertaining to dress for men during fitness activities

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, men-male, health-safety-shmira, sport-athletics

What are the rules pertaining to a male doing a physical activity:

If the kipa keeps falling off, is it necessary to wear it?

What about modesty? If in the comfort of your own home, can you go topless during an exercise?

What about running in the park? Is a t-shirt and shorts outfit fine?

Comment: The tzitzs and yarmulke is a diff question from tzinus.Rav Belsky holds one needs to wear tzitzs while playing basketball see his Shulchan Halevi

Comment: @sam Why? It's not a chiuv to wear tzitzit all the time -- only when wearing a four-cornered garment.

Comment: The Tur writes its correct to always wear a four corner garment ,and It seems like the minhag of klal Yisroel

Answer (score 1):

Regarding kipa - in a shiur I heard from R' Nissin Kaplan, he said that if you can't play a sport without taking off your kipa, then you can't play i.e. it's forbidden to remove your kipa for the sake of playing.  Swimming he said you could for sure take it off, however he said that the Chazon Ish wore a swim cap in the water.

Regarding modesty in your own home - Shulchan Aruch O.C. 2:2, referring to getting dressed, says that a person should not say "I'm alone in my room and no one sees me" and then sit up without a shirt on (instead of putting the shirt on under the covers - 2:1), because Hashem sees everything.  So whatever is inappropriate in public seems to apply in private.

Comment: According to your last paragraph, if taken literally, would require you to shower clothed and use the facilities without revealing anything...I have seen that shulchan aruch, but I think that it should be learned with guidelines for when not to follow it.

Comment: @Ramin Showering has specific guidelines of modesty, e.g. a place where people are normally unclothed and such.  If you exercise in the bathroom, then you're good to go.  But being in private vs. public will not help you was all that I was showing.

Comment: @Yez Shulchan Aruch says this only because before, they slept only with a chaluk and _nothing_  _else_.

Comment: @sem I don't see what difference that makes - is your room a private place or not? I wasn't discussing the application of that particular case, although it's not as simple as you would like it to be. My point is just that laws of modesty apply in private.