# Strictly speaking hilchos tznius for a man

Tags: clothing, tznius-modesty, shiurim-measurements, men-male

Strictly speaking when going to play basketball, what must a man wear in regards to covering his body, I am asking because as I had learned a man has to cover from his breastbone to and including his upper thigh I remember rabbi showing this to me inside and I want to to find the source or find out if I am mistaken,  this would mean that a man can wear a muscle T and shorts to basketball if this is correct or not correct please let me know

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37377/759 or http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38747/759