# Minimum tzniut for men

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, tznius-modesty, men-male, even-haezer

Inspired by this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16101/33665) about the minimum amount of what’s mandatory tzniut  agreed upon, I’m curious what the minimum standard of modesty exists for men. In general Halacha, women are required  to cover more than men I believe, but what is the bare minimum men are expected to dress to be modest?

Comment: This https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38747/759 or one of the linked to questions there is surely a duplicate

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it's a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75354/strictly-speaking-hilchos-tznius-for-a-man , but there's no answer there